# How to navigate between different layout in single Activity

Tags: android, session, navigation, android-activity

In my app I need to maintain the session about user signup details under four pages. At the end of each page have to validate the fields about registration. At the end of fourth page I need to save all user details in database. How can I maintain the session and how could I load each page in a single Activity?Please anyone help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Just store that values into your activity class as member variables.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private String nickname;
    private String password;
    private String mailaddress;
    // ...

    private validateStep1() {
        // doing your checks here
        if(checksPassed) {
            TextView nick = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nick);
            nickname=nick.getText().toString();
            // ...
            showStep2();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do this. One could be a [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) where you 'showNext()' once one page was validated. The data can be stored in your activity...

You could also have one activity for each step and pass the validated values in the intent...

Comment: Thanks jpm..How can i pass more than one activities values to the end of last activity

Comment: what do you mean with 'the end of last activity' ?
When starting an activity with an intent you can add values via intent.putExtra() and then read them in your new activities onCreate.
Although I think the viewFlipper- approach might be nicer...

Comment: Oh and if you meant how to pass data back to a previous activity, you have to start this activity with startActivityForResult and then handle onActivityResult. You can 'pass' data to onActivityResult by setting the result of the other activity before it's finished ( see setResult(int, android.content.Intent)  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int, android.content.Intent) )

Comment: as @user1920666 suggested. using fragments would also be possible. Just add one empty fragment container to your activity, show the first page (a fragment) in this container, when it's done and validated you can store the information (in the activity) and replace this fragment with the next...This is probably the best idea.

Comment: @jpm...I planned to implement this using intents.And now my doubt is,when user has to navigate from activity 2 to activity 1 the fields which he filled will be loaded or not?

Comment: Usually the activity will stay as it was when the user left it. In some cases activities can be killed in the background (e.g. low memory or a task killer). For such cases you should override onSaveInstanceState in your activities, where you can write data into a bundle which is then available in the activity's onCreate() which will be called again, in the case that the activity was destroyed while another activity was visible. (you should use this method anyway to prevent data loss on configuration changes (such as screen orientation)

Answer (score 0):

Create a static string variable for fields you need to keep in database in all your activity one to three.

> ActivityOne.java

```
 Static String NAME= "default123"; //assumed for checking in final(fourth) activity make sure to change it to user given value
```

Then in your last activity you can use something like this:

```
if(ActiviytOne.NAME=="default123"||ActivityTwo.EMAIL=="nomail"){
Toast.makeText(this,"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
else{
//do database operation
}
```